# Is there a way to test/check if tkinter mainloop is running?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I wonder if there is there a way to test/check if tkinter `mainloop` is running somehow? Issuing multiple `tk.Tk().mainloop()` commands will break the GUI, but I haven't found a way to check if `mainloop` has been started for the `tk._default_root`?

Comment: Since it's your code that is starting the mainloop, have you tried setting a flag to know when you've started it? Though, you should be calling it exactly once so it's not clear why you need to know if it's running or not.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley I'm trying to write a library/framework which should be able to be used both with the event loop running or start it itself it not, so it would be convenient if a run check would be possible (as I can check that tk._default_root exists but not if it has been started or not)

Answer (score 2):

Annoyingly, while `Tk().willdispatch()` exists (though it appears undocumented) to lie and say the `mainloop` is running when it isn't (I've used it to allow an `asyncio` task to interlace `asyncio` events with `tkinter` events), there is no Python-level API to *query* the underlying flag (C level struct member `dispatching`) it sets.

The only place the flag is tested is in functions that automatically marshal calls from non-main threads to the `mainloop` thread, and it's not practical to use this as a mechanism of detection (it requires spawning threads solely to perform the test, involves a timeout, and throws an exception when it fails, making it ugly even if you could make it work).

In short, it's going to be on you. A solution you might use would be to make a subclass that intercepts the call to `mainloop` and records that it has been called:

```
class CheckableTk(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.running = False
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def mainloop(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.running = True
        try:
            return super().mainloop(*args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            self.running = False

    def willdispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.running = True  # Lie just like willdispatch lies
        return super().willdispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

It's not a great solution, and I'd discourage it in general. The real answer is, have one, and only one, single place that runs the `mainloop`, instead of splitting up the possible launch points all over your program.

Answer (score 0):

Posting a threading based solution from `matplotlib` source code:

[lib/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py](https://github.com/richardsheridan/matplotlib/blob/699c3c0af3e1a8d35d7e7b398bb739953257268e/lib/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py#L892-L921)

```
def is_tk_mainloop_running():
    import threading
    dispatching = sentinel = object()

    def target():
        nonlocal dispatching
        try:
            tk._default_root.call('while', '0', '{}')
        except RuntimeError as e:
            if str(e) == "main thread is not in main loop":
                print('not dispatching')
                dispatching = False
            else:
                raise
        except BaseException as e:
            print(e)
            raise
        else:
            dispatching = True
            print('dispatching')

    t = threading.Thread(target=target, daemon=True)
    t.start()
    tk._default_root.update()
    t.join()

    if dispatching is sentinel:
        raise RuntimeError('thread failed to determine dispatching value')

    return dispatching
```

Answer (score -3):

If you know the process name, in Windows, you can use psutil to check if a process is running.

Import psutill:

```
import psutil
```

build a function to check if a process is running:

```
def is_running(name: str) -> bool:
    name = name if name.endswith('.exe') else name + '.exe'

    return name in [process.name() for process in psutil.process_iter()]
```

or a function to kill a process:

```
def kill(name: str) -> bool:
    name = name if name.endswith('.exe') else name + '.exe'

    for process in psutil.process_iter():
        if process.name() == name:
            process.kill()
            return True

    return False
```

and then you can simply use them like this

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app_name = 'chrome'

    if is_running(name=app_name):
        if kill(name=app_name):
            print(f'{app_name} killed!')

    else:
        print(f'{app_name} is not running!')
```

Comment: Literally none of this answers the OP's question. The `tkinter` `mainloop` may or may not be running at any time during the lifetime of the process.